# A problem about number of congruence classes in a set

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let us consider a prime, $\ p $,for which we choose $\ s $ different integers,$\ a_1 $ ,$\ a_2 $...$\ a_s $ where $\ s$ < $\ p $ , such that they all are coprime to $\ p $ and belong to different congruence classes modulo $\ p $.

Now let us consider the set $\ A $ of numbers, where any $\ x $ $\ \epsilon $ is of the form  $\sum_{i=1}^s  c_i  a_i$, where $\ c_i$ is either 1 or 0.

There will be $\ 2^s$ numbers in this set as we can see. Can we obtain a lower bound on the number of different congruence classes modulo $\ p $, the set $\ A $ can contain?

Comment: We have $\{0,a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_s\} \subset A$, so we get a lower bound of $s+1$ without much effort. For $s \in \{0,1\}$ we have $s+1 = 2^s$, so that is sharp. For $s = 2$, we can have $3$ or $4$ congruence classes represented in $A$, both options are possible. Clearly, if $s = p-1$, then there will be exactly $s+1 = p$ classes in $A$. I don't know if you can get a larger lower bound for $2 < s < p-1$ without much work.

Comment: This is not an easy problem. There are results on this. But given your other question are you sure you need this for distinct $a_i$?